# Need Help in Configuring Report Scheduler JasperServer

Tags: linux, postgresql, jasperserver

I have JasperServer Community Edition 5.5.0a installed in my Linux server. It is working fine. So I now want to set up report scheduler to be able to have the report in the mail box daily, weekly or monthly. I followed the link [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-report-scheduler). So in file `js.quartz.properties` I have this:

```
quartz.delegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate

quartz.tablePrefix=QRTZ_

quartz.extraSettings=

report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=mail.mydomain.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.username=myname@mydomain.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.password=mypassword
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=myname@mydomain.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol=smtp
report.scheduler.mail.sender.port=xxx

report.scheduler.web.deployment.uri=http://xxxxxxxxxx:8080/jasperserver
```

So I need to restart the JasperServer. Please refer below my finding when I run command through terminal:

- `./ctlscript.sh stop` and got warning `postgresql could not be stopped`
- `kill -9 postgresql` so the postgresql is killed
- `./ctlscript.sh stop` and got warning `postgresql not running`
- `./ctlscript.sh start` and got warning `postgresql could not be started`

I am confused on several things. Does JasperServer requires Postgresql? I don't use Postgresql and till now I can still fetch my report through PHP code. But when I schedule built-in example of JasperServer report, still I don't receive the report in my mailbox. Can somebody help me on how to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link from jasper community.
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-report-scheduler

Comment: thanks but I have checked the link. it is referred from my question actually. I guess for the mail server part is OK but the problem comes when I need to restart the JasperServer